# Javascript code in Qualtrics not working with Internet Explorer (but works fine with other browsers)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, qualtrics

I have a Javascript code for Qualtrics that works fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, but not Internet Explorer.

The purpose of the code is to transfer the ANSWER of the 1st question (a ranking of items) to the text (a list of items) in the 2nd question (so, the order a person ranks the items in the 1st question is the order they appear in text of the 2nd question).  I will post the code I used below.  The current problem in Internet Explorer, is that the 2nd question is not displaying ANY of the items at all.

I am not very proficient with Javascript coding, so I would appreciate any help in understanding what about the code I can include or change to make it incompatible with IE? (without losing functionality in the other browsers).

CODE USED IN 1ST QUESTION:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
/*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/

var QID = this.questionId;
var itemsSet = false;

var curryNextButtonEvent = function(f) {
return function(event) {

if (itemsSet === false) {
//Get items and rank
inputs = $$('#' + QID +' .ChoiceStructure input');
mapping = {};
for(i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
val = inputs[i].value === '' ? i : inputs[i].value-1;
mapping[val] = i;
}
mapping.count = inputs.length;
console.log(Object.toJSON(mapping));
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('QRankedOrder',Object.toJSON(mapping));
itemsSet = true;
}
f(event);
}
}
var nextbutton = $('NextButton');
nextbutton.onclick = curryNextButtonEvent(nextbutton.onclick);
nextbutton.onkeypress = curryNextButtonEvent(nextbutton.onkeypress);

});
```

CODE USED IN 2ND QUESTION:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

//get mapping
try {
mapping = '${e://Field/QRankedOrder}'.evalJSON();
} catch(e) {
console.log('couldn\'t sort',e);
return;
}

//get all elements
eles = $$('.ChoiceStructure li');
parent = eles[0].up();
newOrder = [];
//Make new order of elements
for(i = 0; i < mapping.count; i +=1 ) {
ele = eles[mapping[i]];
ele.remove();
newOrder[i] = ele;
}

//set new order of elements
for(i = mapping.count -1; i >= 0; i-=1) {
if( i % 2 == 1) {
newOrder[i].addClassName('ReadableAlt');
} else {
newOrder[i].removeClassName('ReadableAlt');
}
parent.insert({top: newOrder[i]});
}


});
```

Comment: Check your console in IE, any errors?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  There are errors in IE regardless of the console used or user. Can you clarify what you are asking?